# Does 'thou shalt not steal' refer to general theft or specifically to kidnapping?

Tags: gezel-stealing, aseres-hadibros, negative-commandments

I admit that I sometimes just can't keep my fingers to myself. I felt thirsty so I took a refreshing ginger ale from my neighbour's freezer.

I typed into Google 'thou shall not steal' after realizing that I committed a sin (one day after Yom Kippur... sigh). The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thou_shalt_not_steal) states:

> "Steal" in this commandment has traditionally been interpreted by
>   Jewish commentaries to refer to the stealing of an actual human being,
>   that is, to kidnapping, including human trafficking. With this
>   understanding, a contextual translation of the commandment in Jewish
>   tradition would more accurately be rendered as "Thou shalt not
>   kidnap". Kidnapping would then constitute a capital offence and thus
>   merit its inclusion among the Ten Commandments.
>
> Nevertheless, this commandment has come to be interpreted, especially
>   in non-Jewish traditions, as the unauthorized taking of private
>   property (stealing or theft), which is a wrongful action already
>   prohibited elsewhere in the Hebrew Bible that does not ordinarily
>   incur the death penalty.

Before reading the first paragraph I totally held the second paragraph to be the only truth when it comes to this commandment — and atonement for this sin by repaying the stolen object ("eye for eye, tooth for tooth"). The first paragraph puts it in a different light.

Please elaborate on the idea that stealing in that context might actually mean stealing a human being / human trafficking.

(Is the original Hebrew different and it was mistranslated into English, or did Chazal interpret it this way?)

Comment: While that one reference is understood to be kidnapping, the law against stealing property is also from the Torah, Lev 19:11 "You shall not steal; you shall not deal deceitfully or falsely with one another." I'm also not sure I agree with the causal claim that because something merits a death penalty, it is viable to be in the 10 statements.

Comment: @rosends Right: "Kidnapping would then constitute a capital offence and thus merit its inclusion among the Ten Commandments:" What about desiring another man's goods? Capital offense? Desiring another man's wife? Capital offense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Don't steal" includes don't steal someone's soda.

The "don't steal" commandment appears in both Exodus and Leviticus. Leviticus refers to property, as the next phrase is -- *and don't lie or deny about it.*

Yes, the Talmud says the verse in Exodus refers to kidnapping. But regardless of which verse it is, don't steal! (The punishment is to pay back double, by the way; that way, the thief loses as much as s/he intended to inflict on the other person.)

The reason the Talmud had to identify one verse about kidnapping is an interesting pattern in the Torah -- anytime we find *if one does X, they are liable to the death penalty*, there has to be some other verse that says *thou shalt not do X*. Take a look at Leviticus Ch. 18, for example; there's a series of *thou shalt not* vis-a-vis relationships; then a few chapters later the penalties are listed. So Exodus a few chapters later will say *if someone kidnaps the penalty is death*, which means there must have first been a thou-shalt-not? The Talmud therefore says it was the "don't steal" in the Ten Commandments.

This is all at a very nitty-gritty level. The Ten Commandments are broad and encompass many types of sins; thus, *don't steal* encompasses everything from the harshest possible, kidnapping, to something much smaller.

Comment: There are all types of "stealing", incidentally - some we don't normally think of as "stealing", e.g. "stealing" one's time, by, e.g. browsing in a store when you never had an intention to buy anything. What can prob, be said about any type of stealing is that it may violate a separate prohibition of not "oppressing" your neighbor.